# unable to sum and gave run time error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a sum of Column B that has the 2 items, "B/ 1" and "B/ 2", located at Column A. I am not sure if I have defined it correctly as it didn't do a formulated sum and it gave me Run time error '91'. Thank you in advance for your opinions.

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub tsada()
Dim cell As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Combine").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Each cell In Worksheets("Combine").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)) 

If cell.Value = "B/ 1" Then 
cell1 = cell.Cells(1, 2)
End If

If cell.Value = "B/ 2" Then 
cell2 = cell.Cells(1, 2)
End If

Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 1) = "B total"
Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=sum(cell1,cell2)"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I see a few potential issues. What line raises the error?

Comment: @DavidZemens this line cell1 = cell.Cells(1, 2)

Comment: `cell1` and `cell2` are range objects, you need to do `Set cell1 = ...` and `Set cell2 = ...`

Comment: OH! thanks! Can i check with you how do I create a formula in the cell with cell1 and cell2 doing a sum? It didn't do what was expected but just showing the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell1` and `cell2` are range objects,for an assignment statement, you need to do

```
Set cell1 = ...
```

and

```
Set cell2 = ...
```

Additionally, this formula is almost certain to not evaluate with a `#REF!` error.

```
Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=sum(cell1,cell2)"
```

Try something like:

```
Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=sum(" & cell1.Address & "," & cell2.Address & ")"
```

Extra credit:  try dimensioning a range object instead of a clunky workbook.range.cells construct:

```
Dim rng as Range
With Worksheets("Combine")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)) 
End With
```

Then do:

```
For Each cell in rng.Cells
    '
    '
Next
```

Put it all together, and add a check to make sure your sum won't error:

```
Option Explicit
Sub tsada()
Dim cell As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Combine").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Each cell In Worksheets("Combine").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)) 

If cell.Value = "B/ 1" Then 
    Set cell1 = cell.Cells(1, 2)
End If   
If cell.Value = "B/ 2" Then 
    Set cell2 = cell.Cells(1, 2)
End If

Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 1) = "B total"
If Not cell1 Is Nothing And Not cell2 Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=sum(" & cell1.Address &"," & cell2 & ")"
End If
'# you should probably clear out these variables for the next _
'  iteration , but you may not need to, I don't know enough about _
'  your sheet or what you're trying to do, so this part is up to you
Set cell1 = Nothing
Set cell2 = Nothing

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: its giving me the same error at 

Worksheets("Combine").Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=sum(" & cell1.Address & "," & cell2.Address & ")"

Comment: What else would you expect to happen if either of `cell1` or `cell2` is unassigned?  You do the assignment to these variables in a conditional (`If`) block. If one or both of those conditions do not evaluate to `True`, then you have an unassigned object variable, hence the `91 Object, Variable or With Block not Set` error.

Comment: See revision to my answer above for one way of handling this. I do not know whether you need to clear out the `cell1` and `cell2` variables, but I suspect you might, so I put those lines in the code.  You can remove them, if necessary to suit your needs.

Comment: Great thanks! But just one last question. What if I do not want to lock up the position, for example what I saw over at the cell was something like SUM($B$4,$B$5), I want to remove the $ sign. I change the name 'address' to something else?

Comment: I found it.. I can just add in , (RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) after address if I would like to remove the $ sign. THANKS!

Comment: just another question, i refer to the one you comment earlier regarding unassigned cell. What if B/ 1 isn't available, the code will have an error right?

Comment: I am having the error at the summation line and my guess is because of the "If Not cell1 Is Nothing And ... " line. Even if I changed the And to Or, it still faces the same issue when either B/ 1 or B/ 2 is n.a. any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm try now.  There was an extra comma in the summation statement, I removed that. ALso was missing the `End If` (this is what hapens when I write code without testing it :) )

Comment: the error wasnt coming out from the old revised code, what I mean was what if I have B/ 1 not around, the error will appear... Is there any other way besides using this --> "If Not cell1 Is Nothing And Not cell2 Is Nothing Then" ?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what "What if I have B / 1 not around" means.  Also, if the `If Not ...` logic *works* to avoid the error, then I don't know what you're asking for.  Simply looking for an alternate method of achieving the same result?

Comment: Can you explain why you no longer think this is a suitable answer to your problem?